# am4charts LineSeries tooltip

Tags: amcharts4

Im using AmCharts version 4, and I am trying to get the [Tooltip](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/) to work for my LineSeries.

My chart has to series, one for "new cases" and one for "closed cases".

I tried to use the following but it doesnt work:

> series_closed.tooltipText = \"{valueY.value}\";

**My code:**

```
<script>
am4core.ready(function() {
    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv_cases_created_per_day", am4charts.XYChart);
    chart.data = [
        {
            "y": "Mon 1",
            "created_value": 4,
            "created_color": am4core.color("red"),
            "closed_value": 3,
            "closed_color": am4core.color("green")
        },
        {
            "x": "Tue 2",
            "created_value": 5,
            "created_color": am4core.color("red"),
            "closed_value": 2,
            "closed_color": am4core.color("green")
        },
        {
            "x": "Wed  3",
            "created_value": 7,
            "created_color": am4core.color("red"),
            "closed_value": 2,
            "closed_color": am4core.color("green")
        }
    ];
    // Create axes
    var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "x";
    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());


    // Create series
    var series_created = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series_created.dataFields.valueY = "created_value";
    series_created.dataFields.categoryX = "x";
    series_created.name = "Created";
    series_created.propertyFields.stroke = "created_color";
    series_created.strokeWidth = 1;
    series_created.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";


    // Create series 2
    var series_closed = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series_closed.dataFields.valueY = "closed_value";
    series_closed.dataFields.categoryX = "x";
    series_closed.name = "Closed";
    series_closed.propertyFields.stroke = "closed_color";
    series_closed.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";

    var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
    columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 2;
    columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;



    // Tooltips
    chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();


}); // end am4core.ready()
</script>

<div id="chartdiv_cases_created_per_day" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.

Series need to be named series1, series2 etc.
Not series_created and series_closed.